# Maven - How to customize the build of dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, build, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I have a multi-module maven project like this :

```
project
  project-core
  project-webapp
```

`project-core` is a dependency of `project-webapp`. When building `project-core`, I exclude some elements from the final jar. When I build and deploy the whole project with maven (through m2eclipse), everything is fine.

However, if I build and deploy with WTP, the resource filtering is skipped.

The only work around I have found so far is to disable workspace resolution from m2eclipse. This way, WTP builds the final war with the jar built by maven. The major drawback with this workaround is that I must install, update project each time I modify the `project-core` source code.

How can I force WTP to filter out resources from `project-core` ?

**project/project-core/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
    <name>project-core</name>
    <version>${version.project}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
                // (huge) dependencies list ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>file.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>DIR/file.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
              // repositories ...
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**EDIT:**

> However, if I build and deploy with WTP, the resource filtering is skipped.

Actually I was not doing the filtering at the right *phase*. The resources were filtered only during the jar building. Thanks to @Samuel EUSTACHI, I filter now the resources when they are copied to the `target` folder. Here how I did it :

**project/project-core/pom.xml**

```
        <build>
             <!--
                  I removed completely the plugins node and
                  replace it with the resources node
             -->

             <resources>
                 <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                     <excludes>
                        <exclude>file.properties</exclude>
                        <exclude>DIR/file.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                 </resource>
             </resources>
        </build>
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that WTP does not perform the actual jar build, but rather works with the available resources (probably in target).

It is uncommon to exclude some files from the jar. You could exclude these files from the preceding phases (process-resources ?) or, if you only need these files for Unit Test, move them in test.

It really depends why you decided to exclude them from the jar (you must have a good reason, but it would help to know why).

Comment: I have tried to exclude the files (located in src/main/resources) from the `target` directory through eclipse with no luck. The files still reach the target directory. I could move those files out or src/main/resources but I quite dislike this solution since those files are genuine resources and hey diserve to be in src/main/resources. Actually those files are sample config files for production environment. They already have their counterpart in src/test/resources with special values for testing purpose only.

Comment: If your files are genuine resources, but not part of any build or process (i.e for documentation purpose), you can exclude them this way : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: In my projects, these kind of production samples are nor under  src/main/resources. I place there only the files that are part of the build process, or needed at runtime

Comment: I already do it, check my pom. But WTP don't care about this.

Comment: I can't see, in your poms, anything excluding the files from the early phases of the build. They are excluded from archive (jar) preparation. But this is too late, the resource plugin copies them in target.

Comment: I re-read your link carefully and adapted my pom accordingly. Now everything works like a charm ! Thanks :)